# Grails 2.4.4 and full calendar plugin

Tags: grails, fullcalendar, asset-pipeline

Hi every body i'm facing newbie trouble when i try to have a calendar on my grails app for event. 
I have tried many tutorials but nothing.
So i decided to look into plugin full calendar https://grails.org/plugin/full-calendar but it's working on old version with ressources and without asset pipeline but now in my new grails 2.4.4 version i'm lost and i really want to stay with my asset.
If some one have some ideas 
sorry for english
best regards

Comment: the plugin is for old grails, has no source available for it. Without having tried it the core plugin seems to rely on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/.  so if you download the javascripts and add to your assets site/ declare them and refer to usage am convinced you can get it working.

Comment: already tried but not working may be very bad in jquery

Comment: if you can't make it work then refer to below answer, I hadn't realised it was just a date time picker. Also feel free to look up bootstrap date time picker  too. The framework gives you a lot configuring setting up javascripts are basics of a html website ? how would you do it if you didn't have the plugin

Comment: of course for just time picker it's fine but i nedd calendar for saving event before i try to developp something from scratch i were just looking for poeple who ve already facing there trouble. Like it said no need to force / kick down an unclosed door

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find some thing interesting for other with rich UI
i can have a calendar very easyli with some tags
link http://grails.org/plugin/richui#CalendarMonthView

Comment: That doesn't look like a date time picker  - as i mentioned https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ try looking up bootstrap ways of doing it - that example shows both date/time

Comment: Yeah very interesting link for test on date.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

I use the JQuery datepicker and timepicker in Grails 2.5.5 application and it works fantastic:

Download the jquery.timepicker.min.js (for time picker step unneeded for date pickers) and add to your assets/javascripts directory.

In the GSP:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#intakeDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#screenoutDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#investigatorAssignedDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#intakeTime" ).timepicker({});
});
</script>


   <g:textField name="intakeDate" style="width: 7em" value="${formatDate(format:'MM/dd/yyyy',date:intakeCommand?.intakeDate)}" class="form-control"
                 title="mm/dd/yyyy" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)[0-9][0-9]" />
```

In Config.groovy for binding the MM/dd/yyyy format:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['MM/dd/yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S']
```

Comment: Tks for answer but my interest were about full calendar, i mean day view, week view, month view. the datepicker is working for one date but it's not what i were looking for. thanks again